# Find closest to 0 number from string?

Tags: javascript

I want the number closest to 0 from the string input that consists of numbers separated by ' '. I have coded it in the following manner, it has  worked on first line `temps` variable but did not run correctly in second line `temps` variable. What's missing here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//var temps = "9 -2 -8 4 5"; // get 2 & correct
var temps = "-12 -5 -137";   // get -12 & not correct ,expected 5
var temp = temps.split(" ");
var closest = parseInt(temp[0]);
for(var i = 0;i < temp.length ;i++){
    var t = Math.abs(temp[i]);   
    console.log(typeof closest) ; //number : same type
    if(closest > t) {
        closest = t;
    }
}
console.log(closest);
</script>
```

Comment: @Rajesh `'-1 0 1'.split(" ").sort()[0]`

Comment: @WangYudong I have added an answer using custom sort.

Comment: `temps.split(' ').reduce((a, b) => Math.min(Math.abs(a),Math.abs(b)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing -12 in the

> closest variable

while comparing you are doing this

```
-12>5
```

which is false and so your assignment

```
closest =t;
```

is not being executed. It worked for the first input because there 9 is stored as the closest variable. What you can do is to store the absolute value as the closest variable in this step.

```
var closest = parseInt(Math.abs(temp[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the line

```
var closest = parseInt(temp[0]);
```

by

```
var closest = Math.abs(parseInt(temp[0]));
```

You just missed taking absolute on first index.

Comment: Just a tiny note that you can really start the loop index from 1 as 0 has already been set as closest.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a custom sort function and then select 1 value

```js
function getClosestToZero(str) {
  return str.split(" ").sort(function(a, b) {
    var a1 = Math.abs(a);
    var b1 = Math.abs(b);
    return a1 > b1 ? 1 : a1 < b1 ? -1 : 0
  })[0];
}

var temps = "-12 -5 -137 0 2";
console.log(getClosestToZero(temps))

temps = "11 2 4 5 9 10";
console.log(getClosestToZero(temps))

temps = "-11 -2 -9 3 23";
console.log(getClosestToZero(temps))
```